# Why this delegatecall attack not working?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, security, contract-debugging, bug

I am confused by this simple contract. The main purpose is to bypass the `OnlyContract()` modifier.

Victim contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;

contract Victim {

    modifier OnlyContract() {
        require(msg.sender == address(this), "You are not this contract");
        _;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) external {
        (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{value : amount}("");
        require(success, "Withdraw failed");
    }

    function ContractWithdraw(address payable to_, uint256 value) external OnlyContract {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "No funds");
        (bool success,) = to_.call{value : value}("");
        require(success, "Contract Withdraw failed");
    }
}
```

Malicious Contract

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;

contract Malicious {
    address payable owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    receive() external payable {
        address x = address(0x0000000000);
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = x.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("ContractWithdraw(address,uint256)", address(this), 1000000000000000000));
    }
    
    function Attack() public {
        x.withdraw();
    }
    
    function withdraw_all() public {
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

The flow is like this:

1. Attacker call `Attack()` on Malicious contract.
2. Victim contract send ETH to Malicious contract.
3. Victim contract go into Malicious fallback contract and delegatecall to his own contract.
4. From here, `msg.sender` delegatecall has changed to Victim contract.

But in reality, the delegate call transaction reverted.
I think I've bypassed the `OnlyContract()` modifier.

Why did the attack fail?

Answer (score 2):

Your `OnlyContract()` modifier checks the `msg.sender` and requires `address(this)`.

When `Malicious` `delegatecalls`, the context is `Malicious` which is to say that `OnlyContract` will not be fooled - it will see the foreign address, not its own.

```
Contract A ----- delegates ----> Contract B ---- calls ----> Contract C ---> msg.sender = A


function delegateToB() ...

                                 function doSomethingToC() public view returns(address) {
                                    return C(address).doSomething();



Contract C 

function doSomething() public view returns(address) {
  return msg.sender;
}
```

When A delegates to B, you can conceptualize it as A has *imported* bytecode from B but it continues to execute in the context of A - A's storage, A is msg.sender, address(this) is A (even if the code came from B). So ... when C is called upon to report who, exactly, has called it, it reports A. Your modifier disapproves and it defends the victim.

Hope it helps.